# How do I make it so that it stretches without causing the scroll bars?

Tags: css

I'm trying to stretch the div container to fit the whole window. However whenever I set the width and height to 100%, I still get vertical and horizontal scroll bars that barely scroll anything. Hiding it with:

```
overflow:hidden
```

hides it but then the border on the right and bottom are missing. I want the div to fit exactly as the size of the window.

http://jsfiddle.net/pqDQB/

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do in situations like this is tinker around with the unit I am using.

Step 1: Make sure your content doesn't have any padding or margin that causes your issue.

Step 2: I recommend setting your width to `width: 100vw` and height to `height: 100vh`.  This stands for viewport width and viewport height and will expand your div to cover the whole screen when both are set to 100.